# Ошибка при импорте re, string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется следующий код

```
import re
import string
fhand= open('C:\Python34\west.txt')
reg = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]')
d=dict()
for line in fhand:
    line =reg.sub('',line)
    line = line.lower()
    for c in line:
        if c not in d: d[c]=1
        else: d[c] +=1
t=list()
for key,value in d.items():
    t.append((value,key))
t.sort(reverse=True)
print('\n'.join(str(value) for value in t[1:]))
```

Вчера программа работала, сегодня выдает следующую ошибку: [image]

При этом в папке с написанным кодом появляется папка **pycache** внутри которой скомпилированный файл питона re.cpython-34 со следующим содержимым.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Настроек никаких не менял. Природа ошибки непонятна :(

Comment: Могу предположить, что циклическая зависимость, когда один модуль уже включает другой. То есть скорее всего модуль re подключает модуль string и его подключать уже не надо(или наоборот). К сожалению проверить не на чем.

Comment: Вот Ваш комментарий и навел на мысль, дело в файлах в папке со скриптами оказалось. Один из файлов назывался идентично одной из библиотек :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В папке с исходником программы содержался также файл re.py (на нем учился регулярные выражения строить). Как результат - при команде "import re" обращение шло не к библиотеке, а этому файлу. Мораль: называй файлы правильно.

Comment: Еще одна мораль - изучать Traceback. Можно заметить, что после строки `import re` управление переходит в локальный файл `re.py`